# I need to preform a specific calculation-

Tags: analysis

(I'm sorry I have no clue what something like this is called)

I am writing a program, and I need help writing an expression that calculates the number of lives based on bounds set by the user.

It's a simple number guesser where the user will input the bounds in which the computer will generate a random number. (The variables are called highVal and lowVal).

So if I input 5 & 500 the computer picks a random number between those two and I have x amount of lives to guess what it picked.

My problem is what is x? I tried something like ((highVal - lowVal) / 10) * .13, but that only favors larger bounds because if you pick 0 - 100 it gives you 1 guess (The compiler is set to round out to nearest whole #). Is there an expression that can calculate x for me and give me a semi-balanced number so you don't get too many extra guesses if the bounds are from 0-99999?

Thanks!

Update:
- The user defines the bounds, the program asks for a low number and a high number and the user supplies it with values.
- The bounds will always be over 100 numbers
- The user will input one number (guess) at a time, and then the program will state if their guess is lower or higher than the randomly chosen number by the program (answer)

*I purely want this to be a fair game for both small bounds(100) and larger ones(100000) so that a user cannot purposely give a super large range and get extra guesses, because the guesses are purely dependent on the number of digits between the high and low values, at the moment.

Comment: If the guesser does not know the bounds x could be anything. If they do, then how do they go about guessing? One number at a time? Asking if it is in a range? Your x will be guess strategy dependent.

Comment: What information is given after a guess?  Just whether it is right, or does the computer say whether it is high or low?

Comment: I have updated some information, basically as soon as the user guesses it will tell you if your guess is higher/lower than the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the random number is whole, the user can use binary search to find the number.  If there are $n$ possible numbers you need $\lceil \log_2 (n+1)\rceil $ guesses.  For example, if the numbers range from $1$ to $63$ you need six guesses.  You first guess $32$.  If that fails, you have $31$ numbers left and guess $16$ or $48$ and so on.  You keep guessing the center of the remaining numbers.

Comment: Thank you! If you have time, I'm just curious as to why it's logbase2 and not like e or anything else

Comment: Because you are splitting the list in half each time.  In $n$ guesses you can find one of $2^n-1$ numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If there are $N = hiVal - loVal + 1$ possible numbers, of which one (randomly chosen) is correct, and the user makes $x$ distinct guesses among these numbers, with no information provided other than "right" or "wrong", then the probability of making a correct guess is $x/N$.  If you want that probability to be $p$, you would take $x = Np$.  How you choose to round this to an integer is up to you.

Comment: I forgot to mention that as soon as the user guesses it will tell you if your guess is higher/lower than the answer.